# Projection of vector a onto vector b using vector triple product

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, projection

We know the formula for **projection of a on b** $$ proj_{b} (a)=\left(\frac{a\cdot b}{||b||^2}\right)b = \left(\frac{a\cdot b}{b\cdot b}\right)b$$

and its length is called **component of a in the direction of b** written $$comp_b(a)=||proj_b(a)||=\frac{a\cdot b}{||b||}$$

How can we establish any relationship of above formulas with the following

**Projection using vector triple product?**

[image: Projpart1]

[image: projpart2]

Comment: In the first case you are projecting one vector on a line (the one generated by the other vector). In the second case, you are projecting one vector on a plane.

The only relationship I see is when the author says "The component of $\mathbf v$ in the $\mathbf z$ direction is $\mathbf v \cdot \hat {\mathbf k}$", since $\mathbf v \cdot \hat {\mathbf k} = \dfrac{\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf z}{\Vert \mathbf z \Vert}$.

Comment: @MiguelMars, Thanks, we know $\hat{k}=[0,0,1]$ Now what is the meaning of $\hat{k}\leftarrow a, v \leftarrow b, \hat{k} \leftarrow c$?

Comment: I think the author is explaining that he/she is going to use the formula $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b \times \mathbf c = (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf c) \mathbf b - (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b ) \mathbf c$ substituting those values. So that formula is already known (maybe already proven before in the same text), and it is used to get to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of vector projection of a $\vec{a}$ onto a nonzero $\vec{b}$ and orthogonal projection of $\vec{a}$ onto the plane orthogonal to $\vec{b}$ is equal to $\vec{a}$.

More details are
here $\rightarrow$ [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#:~:text=The%20projection%20of%20a%20vector%20on%20a%20plane,parallel%20to%20the%20plane%2C%20the%20second%20is%20orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#:%7E:text=The%20projection%20of%20a%20vector%20on%20a%20plane,parallel%20to%20the%20plane%2C%20the%20second%20is%20orthogonal).